# SAPUI5 Application login with the Backend and get Data

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

I asked a similar question before but didn't get a right answer because my question was not meaningful or not understandable.

so I try it again..

My Problem is I don't understand how the login works.
My Situation:
I have created a full Application it works, also with the backend. 
My destination is connected to the Cloud Connector .. and it is deployed on the SAP Cloud platform. It works all with the Odata and the SAP GATEWAY Client
For now, I log in with my SAP login data in the application. The thing about it, the application is for all Employees, and all have their sap login. My Application should filter the models according to the staffnumber which is in the sap backend. That's why I need the login. Because all Employees should only see his entries.

Now it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKULc.jpg)

I want a login page.. and after that, I want to get the staffnumber and pass it through the whole app filters.

I hope you understand what I mean.. It's like an application for the Employees and the Employees login in with the SAP Data and sees only their entries according to the staffnumber.

Do I need this? Is there a better way?

Comment: The pop up is the basic authentication setup on the destination / ICF node. I would recommend that your oData back end uses `SY-UNAME` > `PERNR` to limit all your filters. This way people cannot tinker with the name you pass into the service, and get results they're not meant to see.

Comment: Hi, you can do it role based app depending on the user who logins in and what things he can see.  https://help.sap.com/saphelp_hba/helpdata/en/0a/a5665239086d2de10000000a44176d/frameset.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**current setup**

In your current setup, your frontend (ui5 app) is accessed anonymously. When the app accesses the backend through the destination and cloud connector for the first time, the backend asks the user to authenticate themselves. From now on, each request to backend is executed with this user context.

So perfectly fine from authentication point of view (except that you would like to see a nice login screen)

**possible solution(s)**

If you want the user to authenticate on a screen in the cloud, I see two variants:

1. Simple screen with two input fields for user/pw. And doing an Ajax call to backend using BasicAuth  header. Potential security flaw: you could also send the user/pw somewhere else. So the user must trust your app!!
2. Set up Single Sign On using SAML2 (more complex)

**Update**: Just came to mind that your current setup has the same security flaw as the variant 1: the user has to trust your app that it is the backend behind that destination, and not some man-in-the-middle system. So, variant 1 would not introduce any additional risks. And in an enterprise scenario you can ensure by other means that the app and destination can be trusted.

Comment: Hey iPirat thanks for your answer, so i can only go trough the pop up once ? But how do I get the information for the current logged in user? Like the name or the id which i typed in ? Basically I just want the staff number which is in the sap system and I want to filter the entry’s with the staff number which is unique for all employees. I’m a student and it’s a Projekt so I’m kinda a noob. But I try my best and love the work here and want to learn this. The only thing which I don’t really understand is the logging in, and how I get the data behind the logging in popup.. is there a way?

Comment: And I receive the data in the application Only after I logging in with my sap data

Comment: The backend service knows the logged in user. And so it can deduce the staff number

Comment: ahh okay, sooo my logic were dumb.. or not really right. But i got the Odata crud operations.. and there is a set for a list for example.. read the model for the list.. it gives me the whole entrys.. also from the other members. I need to filter it in the backend not in the frontend right? like the sap system knows which user use the read function and filter it after that right? so there is no need for me to filter like i am done it now.. now i have 2 filters for workdate and staffnumber, workdate is a function which is dynamic (on the calendar) and my staffnumber is hard coded..

Comment: so i can in the backend in the operations filter after which user access the function for the get or post or delete and and.. right?

Comment: Assume you have a service that returns a list of data for different employees. And you only need data of one employee. Of the logged in user. Then you need to call the backend first and ask for employee number. Then you filter using that number.