# SAPUI5 Login page?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5

i cant find any simmilar to my question soo i want just to know if i can make a "login page" my own instead of the popup 
[image: this]

this there a way?

My application is deployed on the cloud platform and goes trough a cloud connector to the sap backend system where it get his odata data from..

Its kinda ugly and i cant find anything to this.. except when the app is deployed in the abap repository.. but my is deployed and running trough the cloud platform.

(Username = SAP User and password also sap user pwd) 
so maybe someone can help or paste an example

Comment: That popup is most likely appearing due to chromes default behavior of showing a sign in dialog when it receives a response with status code 401. You can stop this from happening by changing your response to return something other than 401 or you could change the Authorization header to something other than Digest or Basic.

Comment: Now is my authorization on „no authorization“.. if I make basic than I can put my data in it.. but it’s not the idea behinde the app.. It’s for more then one user. So for my understanding.. I cannot make a login page to prevent the popup? I mean the popup should be the login page.. I just want to make it more beautyfull and a own view

Comment: Looks like same issue: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52671995/3434027

Answer (score 0):

This pop-up is appearing for the logon to your ABAP backend system.

> You can simply remove it by setting up Single Sign-On